# How to read Serial data the same way in Processing as C#?

Tags: java, c#, byte, processing

In C#, I use the SerialPort **Read** function as so:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];
int bytesRead = serial.Read(buffer, 0, 100000);
```

In Processing, I use **readBytes** as so:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];
int bytesRead = serial.readBytes(buffer);
```

In Processing, I'm getting the incorrect byte values when I loop over the buffer array from the **readBytes** function, but when I just use the regular **read** function I get the proper values, but I can't grab the data into a byte array. What am I doing wrong in the Processing version of the code that's leading me to get the wrong values in the buffer array?

I print out the data the same way in both versions:

```
for(int i=0; i<bytesRead; i++){ 
    println(buffer[i]); 
}
```

C# Correct Output:
[image]
Processing Incorrect Output:
[image]

Comment: What's incorrect?

Comment: The byte values in the buffer array.

Comment: What's incorrect about them?

Comment: If you give me a sec, I could try to put some output pics of buffer arrays values.

Comment: added some pics

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm curious how Processing is getting negative values for a byte.

Comment: Don't post code in the comment. And that's not enough either way. We need something reproducible if you want concrete assistance.

Comment: @john Bytes are signed in Java.

Comment: @shmosel I converted them to unsigned and the output looks correct now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java bytes are signed, so any value over 128 will overflow.

A quick solution is to do

```
int anUnsignedByte = (int) aSignedByte & 0xff;
```

to each of your bytes.

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing. Are C# bytes unsigned?

Comment: [Yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/byte)